# considerations that should be observed for writing firmware for big projects

Tags: c++, c, microcontroller, stm32, firmware

my issue maybe looks so general but i really need your help .I am a newbie embedded software engineer and I have done some small projects with TI DSC and STM microcontroller with C and C++ programming  languages. but now I am going to start writing firmware for a big project and I am looking for a way to model my firmware before implementing it.actually I have two questions :

1.I want to know what does professional embedded software engineer do before starting to write the firmware ?(for modeling the firmware ,is using from rational rose or enterprise architecture suitable for firmware,i think these two, are suitable for IT and software applications not firmware)

2.what important rules I must observe during writing the firmware?
for example I have considered about :

a.Never ever put a lot of code into an interrupt service routine

b. Never  do busy waiting with wile loops
What other thing should I have considered?

Comment: Just from personal experience of being on the other end of firmware, if it's going to have an API that someone else has to interact with make sure you've asked them what they need before you write it.

Comment: First things first: Gather requirements! Make use-case studies! Find out what is needed! Then make an analysis from the information you have. Continue with making a design from the analysis. Then continue making test-cases. And then you implement the design, and make sure it passes the test-cases. Iterate over any step, or over multiple steps, as much as is needed.

Comment: thank you for answer ,do you have used any modeling design tools based on UML in your work or it is not necessary for firmware? (like Enterprise Architect )

Comment: In my personal experience of UML and similar concepts, the point of it is to demonstrate to yourself and others you've actually thought about how you're going to do it. You'd be surprised how many only really think about these things half-way through and have to start over.

Comment: UML is mostly useful for illustrating your design in a standardized way. It is by no means necessary. What _is_ necessary is common sense and lots of programming experience. Making the design is the most qualified part of a software project, so the most experienced people in the team should be doing it (and thereby teaching the rookies).

Comment: As for all the project management bullshit about Agile waterfalls TDD... don't put effort into that, as they all, at best, boil down to common sense in the end. And you _always_ end up with the classic analysis -> design -> implementation -> test phases no matter which buzzword you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These kind of questions are off-topic on SO, but I'll answer anyway since there's not really a forum anywhere for these very important considerations. Typically it goes like this:

Write the spec and requirements. Spend some time at this and focus on the product, not on technical details. UML "use-cases" can be handy but common sense works just as fine too. Make sure that the spec is a living document which can be revised when necessary.

Then do the program design with an OO model (call it classes/code modules/translation units or what you will). Write down which code modules that the program need, make sure these correspond to the spec - ideally each requirement leads to specific code (which later on leads to a specific test of that code). Then focus on dependencies between different modules: this should be a "top-to-bottom" dependency tree where drivers don't depend on HALs, that don't depend on callers and so on. Draw up this tree with pen and paper. Fancy UML is ok but not necessary.

You need to consider portability early on. Should the code be ported between projects? (very common) Between compilers? (fairly common) Between platforms? Depending on what level of portability that is needed, you can cheat with the design and skip some HALs. It is almost always a good idea to separate the drivers from the application, however.

Regarding "important rules" these have nothing to do with the program design stage. Rather, these should be in your coding standard document. Preferably a company standard that is used for every project. It should focus on banning all manner of bad practices and in addition contain a style guide. For embedded systems I would strongly recommend to base this document on MISRA-C, then add custom rules if you wish (such as "keep ISR code minimal") and then add a style guide on top of that. Please note that writing this coding standard is a project of its own.

Comment: I feel that point about modularity is the most important point in this answer. Other mistakes, such as lacking portability and bad style are easier to fix (although they should not be ignored the first time) when codebase is not horrible spaghetti with dependencies all over the place.

Comment: @user694733 Indeed. Embedded programmers coming from small-scale projects with little or no program design often fail to realize why this is necessary. So they write everything without modularity, ending up with incredibly tight coupling: everything in the program depending on everything else. Hundreds of boolean "flags" and obscure state variables in the global scope, plus spaghetti global data. It just becomes more and more unmaintainable until it hits the critical mass and just bugs out permanently. There's not really a way to restore such programs, they have to be rewritten from scratch.

Comment: @Lundin very good point. But there is the another side of this metal. Focusing on modularity and abstraction sometimes leads to the exactly same effects as you if the coder completely do not care about it. MISRA-C is a good starting point as this standard was developed and evolved on the real firmware issues. I am quite often critisied here because I prefer one return point in the function as it makes code cleared and more readable for humans, with no or minimal overhead.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 Program design is quite a delicate task indeed. On one hand you don't want to end up with no design at all, as that will always result in tight coupling and spaghetti. On the other hand, you don't want bloated, unintuitive abstraction layers that fill no purpose by themselves and also reduce performance. Those are the two extremes, good design is somewhere in the middle.

Comment: @Lundin Exactly - my comment is not very understandable as i wrote it on my mobile. That ` as you` should be 'as you mentioned' :)

Comment: one return point adds code and makes it less readable.  sometimes adding more than just high level language code but more actual code in the binary.  more lines of code is more risk, less reliable.     the OP needs to venture through various experiences, try different things, fail some.  find what works for them.  so in that light misra is fine but has its problems, do 178 is fine, but not perfect, nothing is perfect otherwise we would all be using it with the perfect language and perfect compiler...

Comment: @old_timer thinking is the most required activity during the programming. You wrote about the "thick as brick" guidelines followers.